# Logistic Regression output not significant

Tags: r, regression, logistic

used the glm function in R to model a logistic regression of a binary repsonse and 3 categorical predictors. My problem is that according to the summary non of the levels is significant.

Answer (score 2):

That happens sometimes even with the ordinary regression analysis. Individual coefficients (their z-values) are not significant when whole regresssion model is significant by the F-test.

Comment: the problem ist that non of the over 600 levels is significant...so this happens quite a lot. Is there some way to change my data to get better results?

Comment: What are the 600 levels? You have a binary response and three predictors?